# Porque este fetch me devuelve este error?

Tags: reactjs

Este es mi fetch

```js
   var code = this.props.location.query.code
fetch (`https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token/?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=xxxxx&code=`+code+`&accept=json`, {
    method: 'GET',
  })
```

Error

```
Fetch API cannot load https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token/?client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&code=c48c0c8d5a01db2f6fc6&accept=json. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://5e9d9e3b.ngrok.io' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Estoy intentando hacer un login con Oauth de GitHub entonces cuando me devuelve el code le hago otro este fetch para que me devuelva por respuesta json el acces_token del usuario el cual voy a almacenar en un `localStorage` para así despues poder trabajar con el.

Comment: Ahi dice `'http://5e9d9e3b.ngrok.io' is therefore not allowed access` osea que github no le da el acceso para poder hacer el login.

Comment: http://5e9d9e3b.ngrok.io este enlace es un tunnel que uso para que funcione el callback de github, porque logicamente no le puedo poner localhost que es donde tengo el sitio, entonces cree un tunel y me devuelve a eso que seria lo mismo que devolverme el callback a mi ip, pero en mi pais hay ip dinamica por lo tanto debo usar eso

Comment: http://5e9d9e3b.ngrok.io tiene que estar definida en la `Authorization callback URL` del Github .

Comment: y otro problema es que el `client_id` y `client_secret` se ven por eso lo tienes que hacer en un servidor interno.

Comment: Ah buen, punto. Si el ngrok esta en el callbak url de github pero creo que mejor lo hare desde el backend asi no se ve esos datos. Gracias

Comment: (node:75531) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0 el backend me devuelve esto al hacerla desde ahi